# cannot add new field to sales flat table in magento CE 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, sales-order, setup-script

I  wrote module which will  create a new varchar field in sales_flat_order.
For this  we create seutp set but it not working ,where the issue:
app/code/local/Bh/Affiliate/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bh_Affiliate>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Bh_Affiliate>
    </modules>
    <global>    
        <models>    
        <affiliate> 
            <class>Bh_Affiliate_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>affiliate_resource</resourceModel>
            </affiliate>
             <affiliate_resource>
                <class>Bh_Affiliate_Model_Resource</class>
                </affiliate_resource>
        </models>
            <resources>
             <affiliate_setup>
                  <setup>
                   <module>Bh_Affiliate</module>
                   <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Setup </class>
                 </setup>
            </affiliate_setup>
            </resources>
    <fieldsets>
          <sales_convert_quote>                          
                <affiliate_details><to_order>*</to_order></affiliate_details>
            </sales_convert_quote>

            <sales_convert_order>                                             
                <affiliate_details><to_quote>*</to_quote></affiliate_details>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>

    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <affiliate>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Bh_Affiliate</module>
                    <frontName>affiliate</frontName>
                </args>
            </affiliate>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Bh/Affiliate/sql/affiliate_setup/install-1.0.0.php

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$options = array(
    'type'     => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
    'visible'  => false,
    'required' => false
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'affiliate_details', $options);

$installer->endSetup();
/*
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute(
    'order', 
    'affiliate_details', 
    array(
        'type' => 'varchar', 
        'grid' => false 
    )
);
$installer->endSetup();
*/
/*
$installer = $this;

$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'), 'affiliate_details', array(
        'TYPE'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
        'LENGTH'    => 255,
        'NULLABLE'  => true,
        'COMMENT'   => 'Affiliate Details'
    ));


*/
```

app/etc/modules/Bh_Affiliate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bh_Affiliate>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Bh_Affiliate>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: `/sql/Affiliate_setup/install-1.0.0.php` should be `/sql/affiliate_setup/install-1.0.0.php`...lowercase `a`.

Comment: @marius it was my typo mistakes.Now check  where the issue ..

Comment: Check the table `core_resource` for a record with code `affiliate_setup`. If there is one, remove it.

Comment: have the records...affiliate_setup in table

Comment: This means that the install script was executed once, or the you added the install script to the extension after magento already knew about it. Try deleteing that record and see what happens.

Comment: ya , i have already do this ..but it not working

Comment: Are you there @Marius??

Comment: I have no other ideas.

Comment: can you please try my extension on your system,for checking the issue

Comment: tried it. It works fine. Make sure you cleared the cache after removing the record from `core_resource`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution ,Just change the  setup class

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Setup
```

To

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup
```

And it work now.

Comment: This have been discussed long before this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13897753/2375207